# function calls during recursion

Tags: java, function, recursion, concept

Suppose, in a recursive problem, we call the function as follows:

```
class MazePaths{
public static int countPaths(int n, int m, int i, int j){
    // base cases
    if(i == n-1 && j == m-1) // only 1 path possible from this point to the destination point
    return 1;
    if(i == n || j == m)
    return 0;
    // end of base case

    // to move down
    int downpaths = countPaths(n, m, i+1, j);

    //to move right
    int rightpaths = countPaths(n, m, i, j+1);

    
    return rightpaths+downpaths;

}// end of function countPaths
```

My question is when we are assigning int values to rightpaths and downpaths, we are merely calling the function by increasing the value of either i or j; the function is not performing any operations but just calling its copy with the updated value of a variable. Then what are the values which are getting assigned to the 'downpaths' and the 'rightpaths' variables, which we are returning at the end after adding them with each other?

Answer (score 0):

the operation its preforming is adding rightpaths and downpaths,
what I mean by that is each time this if statement will be true

```
if(i == n-1 && j == m-1) // only 1 path possible from this point to the destination point
return 1;
```

1 will be added to your final answer

another way to look at this is:
the values of rightpaths and downpaths will be the number of paths from the points (n, m, i+1, j) and (n, m, i, j+1), and to be more technical
the number of the recursive calls the will return True for the if statement

```
if(i == n-1 && j == m-1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can now understand that each time both the conditions are satisfied, it means that we have successfully reached our destination point, and 1 valid path is generated. But can you please tell me the significance of the statement `return rightpaths+downpaths;` ? What is being added there when the `return 1;` is the one adding up the number of paths?

Comment: it means the number of different paths you have from a certain point equals the number of the path you have should you choose to go down plus the number of paths should you choose to go right
I.E if you have one path once you chose to go down and one path, once you choose to go right  'downpaths', will equal1 and 'rightpaths' will equal 1 so 'return rightpaths+downpaths;' will return 2 witch is the number of all the different paths you can take :)